# Doubt on a particular commutative diagram using the Tensor Product construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, diagram-chasing

I've posted two other questions* $[1]$ $[2]$, discussing and asking about the Tensor Product construction, in particular the "**canonical construction**", which is the one $[4]$:

$$ \frac{F(V \times W)}{S} := V\otimes W. \tag{1}$$

Now, due to isomorphism $L$ induced by the machinery of tensor product we can say then that the vector space $Z$ and $V\otimes W$ are isomorphic. Therefore, we can say that elements of $Z$ are tensors,i.e. $(V\otimes W, \otimes) \approx (Z, b)$:

$$\begin{array}{rcl} V \times W & \overset{\otimes}{\to} & V \otimes W \\ b & \searrow & \downarrow L \\ \, & \, & Z \end{array} Figure \hspace{1mm}1$$

My doubt is: **Since $(V\otimes W, \otimes) \approx (Z, b)$, can I construct another commutative diagram like Figure 2, and say that the pair $(Z, b)$ is the tensor product for another bilinear map $\phi$?**

$$\begin{array}{rcl} V \times W & \overset{b}{\to} & Z \\ \phi & \searrow & \downarrow L' \\ \, & \, & \mathbb{R} \end{array} Figure \hspace{1mm}2$$

$$ --- \circ---$$

$*$ I'm not referring my own questions aiming more answers, it's just to show self-study progression.

$[1]$ [Doubt on the understanding of the role of Quotient Spaces on Tensor Product construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624608/doubt-on-the-understanding-of-the-role-of-quotient-spaces-on-tensor-product-cons)

$[2]$ [Doubt on the notation of the generators of the subspace $S \subset F(V \times W)$ in tensor product construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631044/doubt-on-the-notation-of-the-generators-of-the-subspace-s-subset-fv-times-w)

$[3]$ [Understanding the Details of the Construction of the Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/understanding-the-details-of-the-construction-of-the-tensor-product)

$[4]$ ROMAN.S; *Advanced Linear Algebra*

$[5]$ CONRAD.K; *Tensor Products I*. https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

Comment: What does"tensor product for another bilinear map $ϕ$" mean?

Comment: Means, for example, the inner product map.  What I want to know is if I could do what I ask above. Acctually I want more. Suppose that $Z = L(V^{*} \times W^{*},\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of bilinear forms considering the duals. Then, by tensor product construction we say that elements of $L(V^{*} \times W^{*},\mathbb{R})$ are tensors because $V\otimes W \approx L(V^{*} \times W^{*},\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @NoelLundström also since they are isomorfic, we can say that the pair $(L(V^{*} \times W^{*},\mathbb{R}), b )$ is a tensor product. Then we can construct another commutative diagram like figure 2, and study bilinear maps like inner product.

Note that we cannot state that $b = \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ because $Z = L(V^{*} \times W^{*},\mathbb{R})$. Conversely, we cannot say that $V\otimesW = L(V^{*} \times W^{*},\mathbb{R}) $ in the first place, because we need to construct the tensor product.

Comment: in your formula (1) it should be $=:$ instead